# Add column to a table

Tags: text-processing

I have several ASCII files, having one column of data, as follows:

```
DATA
1564
1896
1238
1479
1562
1894
1489
....
```

I need to implement a column containing the date. I know that the each data set begins in 1900-01-01 (Year-Month-Day). Therefore, I would like to reformat each file as follows:

```
DATE DATA
1900-01-01 1564
1900-01-02 1896
1900-01-03 1238
1900-01-04 1479
1900-01-05 1562
1900-01-06 1894
1900-01-07 1489
.....
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Will the dates change month as well? And year? Or are there less than 30 lines per data set?

Comment: @terdon - The data sets extend over month, years and days (unfortunately), with random lengths of the time series

Comment: OK, and what operating system are you using? Do you have access to GNU tools (if you're running Linux, the answer is yes, otherwise it's "maybe").

Comment: @terdon - I am using (unfortunately) windows. BUT I access a Linux cluster using "putty". Therefore the operating system is Linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have access to GNU `date`, you can do:

```
$ ( date="1899-12-31"; printf 'DATE\tDATA\n';  
    tail -n+2 file | 
        while read line; do 
            date="$(date -d "$date + 1 day" +%F)" 
            printf '%s\t%s\n' "$date" "$line"
        done; ) > newfile
```

#### Explanation

- `date="1899-12-31"` : set the variable `$date` to the start date minus one day.
- `printf 'DATE\tDATA\n';` : print the column headers.
- `tail -n+2 file |` : print everything except the first line (the header)  of your file, and pass that to the `while` loop.
- `while read line; do ... ; done` : process each input line, saving it as `$line`.
- `date="$(date -d "$date + 1 day" +%F)"` : add one day to the value of `$date`.
- `printf '%s\t%s\n' "$date" "$line"` : print the current `$date` and `$line` variables.
- `( ... ) > newfile` : this makes the entire command run in a subshell so you can capture the output of the first `printf` and the loop and redirect it into `newfile`.

Comment: That works for me only on 64-bit builds; 32-bit appears to be using 32-bit-signed time_t, which can't go before 1901-12-13T20:45:52Z (or after 2038-01-19T03:14:07Z, which is much better known and more worried about)

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "DATE\tDATA\n"

offset=0

sed -n '2,$p' |
while read data; do
        thedate=$( gdate -d "1900-01-01 + $offset days" +"%F" )
        printf "%s\t%s\n" "$thedate" "$data"
        (( ++offset ))
done
```

This little script is run with

```
$ bash script.sh <data
DATE    DATA
1900-01-01  1564
1900-01-02  1896
1900-01-03  1238
1900-01-04  1479
1900-01-05  1562
1900-01-06  1894
1900-01-07  1489
```

It prints the header and skips the first line of input from the input file (containing the header "`DATA`").

It computes the date for the current line as an offset from 1900-01-01 using GNU `date` (which is called `gdate` on my system, if it's called just `date` on your system, change that line).

It then outputs the computed date in the correct format along with the data read from the input, in two tab-delimited columns.